# How can I collect data on all BrowserWindows synchronuously in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I have an app where I spawn several BrowserWindows, with html forms, and I'd like to collect all the data (in order to save it, to be able to spawn them in the same state at a restart) at a press of a button.

At the moment, the only solution I found to do so, is to have each BrowserWindow do ipcRenderer.send every single time any variable changes (not too hard to do with Vuejs 'watchers'), but this seems demanding and inefficient.

I also thought of doing 'executeJavascript' to each window but that does not allow to capture the return value afaik.

I'd just like to be able to send a message from main when a request for saving is made, and wait for the windows to respond before saving all.

EDIT

I found a slightly better way, it looks like this

**app.js**

```
  // wait for update reponses
  ipc.on('update-response', (evt,args) => {
    updates[evt.sender.id] = args;
    if(Object.keys(updates).length == BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length) {
        // here I do what I need to save my settings, using what is stored in 'updates'
        // ...
        // and now reset updates for next time
        updates = {}
    }
  });

  // now send the requests for updates
  BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().map(w => w.send('update'));
```

**renderer.js**

```
ipcRenderer.on('update', () => {
    // collect the data
    // var data = ...
    ipcRenderer.send('update-response', data);
})
```

and obviously on the renderer side I am listening to these 'update' messages and sending data with 'udpate-response'.

But it seems a bit complicated and so I am sure there is a simpler way to achieve this using the framework.

EDIT 2

I realized that the above does not always work, because for some reason, the evt.sender.id do not match the ids obtained from BrowserWindows.getAllWindows(). I worked around that by sending ids in the request, and having the responder include it. But this is all so much fine for so very little...

Comment: Perhaps you could in your preload add a form change listener which will send an IPC received by the main

Comment: well that's what I did (that's what I meant with Vuejs 'watchers') but it seems clumsy

Comment: My thought would be each window is responsible for its own state but listens for a global event saying send data.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Yes, I send the message on ipc, which is received by the windows, which each act according to the listener I created.